# Angular, NgRx how to use RxJS operator in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a small problem to understand combine RxJS operators with NgRx. Below I have a simple component with NgRx store - there I have all necessary data and the selectors are working properly:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    selector1$: Observable<any>;
    selector2$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private store$: Store<StoreModel>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        selector1$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1));
        selector2$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1));
    }

}
```

But - I would like to using RxJS operators - for example using `withLatestFrom` and calling there 2 selectors - where I should start `.pipe`?

I.

```
ngOnInit() {
    pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
            this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1));
            this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue2));
        ),
        map(([respValue1, respValue2]) => {}
}
```

II. Or by `this.store$`:

```
this.store$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1));
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue2));
    ),
    map(([respValue1, respValue2]) => {}
}
```

III. or like I./II. but using arrow?

```
this.store$.pipe(combineLatest(
    this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1)),
    this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue2)),
    (respValue1, respValue2) => {
        return `${respValue1} + ${respValue2}`})).subscribe(console.log);
```

All of the solutions are not working. I should create new observable value for calling RxJS operators? Or what is the best solution for that case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on what behavior you want to get

Comment: I would like to call 2 selectors check if one of them is null - should be - if yes, dispatch action.

Comment: Never do that. Use a selector to combine your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withLatestFrom()` is not an "Observable creation method" so you'll probably want to use `combineLatest()` instead (also, `withLatestFrom()` works differently than `combineLatest()`).

```
combineLatest([
  this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1)),
  this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1)),
]).subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
  // do whatever you want here
})
```

Comment: Can I check value from selectValue1 before dispatch action in subscriber? I would like dispatch new action only when got value (I would like to check that value) from select1....

Comment: So you don't want to be using `selectValue2` at all?

Comment: In main component I called dispatch action, which one fetching data to store. Select value1 is a boolean which one is false - when fetching data from dispatch action was stopped or true - during fetching that data. I would like combine multiple selectors - but only when fetching data is false. Now - in combineLatest - two selector starting at the same moment. And always I got undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1)),
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue2))
    ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Edit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue1)),
        this.store$.pipe(select(selectValue2))
    ).pipe(tap(console.log))
        .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: But if I would like to use pipe with another operators? Or using map? Before subscribe I can put pipe and add another parameters?

Comment: Thank You. I can't put pipe or subscribe in that place. Have the error - ```TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, string, string[]]>```'

Comment: Oh, I thought it said `combineLatest` instead. `withLatestFrom` is a pipeable operator, you probably want `combineLatest`.

Comment: Use selectors instead of combining data through observables

Answer (score 0):

Why not keeping it simple, and combine selectors with `createSelector`? 
This will also lead to lesser change detections.

```
export const selectValueOneAndTwo = createSelector(
  selectValue1, 
  selectValue2,
  (one, two) => one + two
)
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    selector$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectValueOneAndTwo));
}
```